# facebook ios api post to page - link or message

Tags: objective-c

I have created a page on facebook and want to post to that page. My facebook user is the administrator of the page. With the request "me/account" I get back the access_token and id for that page and the code below posts to that page.

```
Facebook* facebook = app.facebook;

NSDictionary* pg = [fbpages objectAtIndex:0]; // page access_token, id and name 
NSLog(@"page %@\n",[pg valueForKey:@"name"]);

NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];       

NSString *graphPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/feed", [pg valueForKey:@"id"] ];
[params setObject:[pg valueForKey:@"access_token"] forKey:@"access_token"];
[params setObject:@"This is my message coming from my ios app." forKey:@"message"];

// ----- specify that this is a link ----------------------
[params setObject:@"link" forKey:@"type"];
[params setObject:@"http://www.whatever.com" forKey:@"link"];
// ------ this is the difference between case 1 and 2 -----

[facebook requestWithGraphPath:graphPath andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:app];
```

Now, the weird thing is, (case1) if I post a simple message (without the specify link part), it appears on the page as it was posted by the page, (case2) but when the link info is there, it appears as my post.
case1 - appears on the **LEFT** side of the timeline as a simple message 
case2 - appears on the **RIGHT** side of the timeline as "others post", and the page is not rendered, but only shows an "attachment" sign.

Apart from the two parameters "type" and "link", case 1 and 2 identical. 
Anyone experienced the same issue? Any suggestions? What am I doing wrong?
I want my link posted to the page appear the same way as it appears on user's wall.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured out myself. If I call the requestWithGraphPath with the token for a given page, it works as expected.

So it looks like:

```
facebook.accessToken = [pg valueForKey:@"access_token"];
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:graphPath andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:app];
```

Obviously, you need to reset the original accessToken when the request is completed.